# Combine/Merge two MYSQL SELECT statements into one

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for help using a single `SELECT` statement. Example using two statements:

> 1st: get 40 days from now out to 365 days from now
>
> 2nd: get NOW out to 40 days

equals all 365 days offset 40 days from now

select statement 1:

```
SELECT id FROM sales
 WHERE (saledate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
 ORDER BY saledate;
```

select statement 2:

```
SELECT id FROM sales
 WHERE (saledate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY))
 ORDER BY saledate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `or`?

```
SELECT id
FROM sales
WHERE (saledate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) OR
       (saledate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY))
ORDER BY saledate;
```

Of course, this can be simplified further:

```
SELECT id
FROM sales
WHERE saledate BETWEEN (NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
ORDER BY saledate;
```

This seems so obvious, though, that I might be missing something.

EDIT:

If this is an ordering issue, then `union all` is *not* the way to go.  Unions do not guarantee the ordering of the results.  Instead, just do:

```
SELECT id
FROM sales
WHERE saledate BETWEEN (NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
ORDER BY (saledate >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY) ) DESC,
         saledate;
```

Comment: The issue is that I need the results to be ordered "starting" 40 days out while still showing all 365 days. A little strange I know...

Comment: @Airman . . . See, I was missing something.  If you want results in a particular order, you should use `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a combined result using `UNION` like

```
(SELECT id FROM sales 
WHERE (saledate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY) 
AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) 
ORDER BY saledate)

UNION

(SELECT id FROM sales 
WHERE (saledate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 40 DAY)) 
ORDER BY saledate)
```

Comment: Maybe? I have not tried UNION. I'm still learning MYSQL. Will it order the results by date respectively

Comment: If I want to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS do I just add it to the first SELECT statement only? i.e. SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id FROM ...

Comment: @Airman, NO, I think you should get that for the result set of the entire query.